# Concatenate text files using FileChannel

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to concatenate a set of text files using the following method. However, only the first file is show in the output file.

```
public void concatenateFiles(List<String> fileLocations, String outputFilename){
try(FileChannel outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename).getChannel()) {
    long position = 0;
    for(String fileLocation: fileLocations){
        try(FileChannel inputChannel = new FileInputStream(new File(fileLocation)).getChannel()){
            position += inputChannel.transferTo(position, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Do you see any problems?

Comment: How would I solve the problem?

Comment: Does this compile for you?

Comment: yes it does and it doesn't return any error on the unit test, except that the output file is not what is supposed to be.

Comment: Can you give us your sample input and its respective results ?

Comment: @Mohammad S. , Do you mean try(...)? It is a try-with-resources statement. After try block finished, all resources that are declared inside parentheses freed.

Comment: @MohammadS. yes as Nicolai mentioned. This is Java 7 convention.

Comment: @Nicolai Thanks.  I didn't know Java7 had this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
    position += inputChannel.transferTo(position, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
```

to

```
    position += inputChannel.transferTo(0, inputChannel.size(), outputChannel);
```

The first parameter is a start position for reading  inputChannel

Comment: Yes, for combine files it is unnecessary.